# Powershell: I need to convert AD manager field into an email address and then populate the managers email into an extensionattribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have found out how to get the manager's email address using

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties * | select Displayname, EmailAddress, @{Name="ManagerEmail";Expression={(get-aduser -property emailaddress $_.manager).emailaddress}}
```

I then want to filter out for a test so added in

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties * | select Displayname, EmailAddress, @{Name="ManagerEmail";Expression={(get-aduser -property emailaddress $_.manager).emailaddress}} | ? { ($_.EmailAddress -like "testuser@domain.com")
```

This all works as expect and shows me the fields I need but I need to pipe the manager email address into an extensionAttribute. So I thought I could add in

```
$user = "testuser@domain.com"|Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Add @{extensionAttribute13 = ManagerEmail}
```

This fails though. Can anyone assist in getting the managers email address into the extension attribute?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: You're a bit too keen to pipe everything together without ever capturing what you need later in a variable like the user you want to set the extension attribute on.. Then you do `-Properties *` where you really only want two properties, so that's a waste. In the third code, you are setting a variable as **string** and again try to pipe that through to Set-ADUser, which won't work. Do yourself a favor and start writing multiline code. By cramming it all into oneliners, you will make mistakes that are hard to spot.